# printf and memcpy linkage to standard C library

Tags: c

It is my understanding that if I call `printf` in a program, by default (if the program isn't statically compiled) it makes a call to `printf` in the standard C library. However, if I were to call say `memcpy`, I'd hope the code would be inlined, as a function call is very expensive if `memcpy` is only copying a few bytes. If you're inlining sometimes and calling out others, the behaviour of your program after a libc upgrade is implementation dependent.

What actually occurs in both of these cases and generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depend on a lot of things, here's how you can find out. GNU Binutils comes with a utility `objdump` that gives all sorts of details on what's in a binary.

On my system (an ARM Chromebook), compiling test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

with `gcc test.c -o test` and then running `objdump -R test` gives

```
test:     file format elf32-littlearm

DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE 
000105e4 R_ARM_GLOB_DAT    __gmon_start__
000105d4 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   puts
000105d8 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   __libc_start_main
000105dc R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   __gmon_start__
000105e0 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   abort
```

These are the dynamic relocation entries that are in the file, all the stuff that will be linked in from libraries external to the binary. Here it seems that the `printf` has been entirely optimized out, since it is only giving a constant string, and thus `puts` is sufficient. If we modify this to

```
printf("Hello world #%d\n", 1);
```

then we get the expected

```
000105e0 R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT   printf
```

To get `memcpy` to be explicitly linked to, we have to prevent `gcc` from using its own builtin version with `-fno-buildin-memcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all the function is never truly "inlined" - that applies to functions that you've written that are visible in the same compilation unit.

> If you're inlining sometimes and calling out others, the behaviour of your program after a libc upgrade is implementation dependent.

This is not the case. The `memcpy` might be "inlined" at *compile time*. Once compiled, your libc version makes no difference.

In GCC, `memcpy` is recognized as a [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).  That means if GCC decides it, the call to `memcpy` will be replaced with a suitable implementation.  On x86, this will usually be a `rep movsb` or similar instruction - depending on the size of the copy, and if it is of a constant size or not.

Answer (score 2):

An implementation is allowed by the C standard to behave "as if" the actual standard library function were called.  This is indeed a common optimization: small `memcpy` calls can be unrolled/inlined, and much more.

You're right that in some cases you could upgrade your `libc` and not see any change in function calls which were optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

You can always attempt to drive the compiler behavior. For instance, with `gcc`:

```
gcc -fno-inline -fno-builtin-inline -fno-inline-functions -fno-builtin...
```

You should check the different results with `nm` or directly the interrupt calls in the assembly source code.